# How to disable LLMNR on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, systemd-resolved

My understanding is that if I am using third party DNS (Google, etc.)
or DNS provided by my ISP (Comcast, etc.),
I do not need the LLMNR feature on. 
I am attempting to disable it, but setting `LLMNR=no` in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and restarting the box does not seem to work.

I am on Ubuntu 17.10. 
How can I go about achieving this goal?

Comment: LLMNR and DNS are not mutually exclusive, they complement each other. LLMNR only resolves link-local names, i.e. the names of the computers on your local LAN. A "third-party" DNS server, on the other hand, does not resolve your link-local host names to IP addresses, unless you have registered your own domain and entered records for your hosts.

Comment: How did you determine that LLMNR was disabled after editing the config file? Also note that you will have to ensure `MulticastDNS` is also turned off, since mDNS provides a similar service.

Answer (score 0):

After adding `LLMNR=no` to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` you should start the `systemd-resolved.service` service:

```
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved.service
```

Then create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

enable the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
```

Comment: Since the OP was asking how to disable LLMNR, he/she already had `systemd-resolved` enabled and running. A restart is probably a good idea after changing the configuration, though.

Comment: @JohanMyréen By default the `systemd-resolved` is disable also making the `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` accessible from `/etc/resolv.conf` by creating a symlink.

Comment: The OP asked how to disable LLMNR provided by `systemd-resolved`, so I don't see how this applies to a situation were `systemd-resolved` was not enabled, regardless of what the default is.